# Python kivy show the text of the text input in other widget?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making an app in python kivy and I'm trying to show the text of the text input in another widget like a label whenever I "release" my "close button" How can I do that? Below is my code!

main.py

```
            layout = GridLayout(cols=1, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=30,
                                spacing=80)
            popuptextinput = TextInput(hint_text='Name',
                                       multiline=False,
                                       background_color='blue',
                                       halign='left',
                                       cursor_blink=True,
                                       cursor_color='white',
                                       foreground_color='white',
                                       font_size='14')
            closebutton = Button(text="SAVE", background_color="black", font_size="14",
                                 font_name='Sackersz.otf')
            layout.add_widget(popuptextinput)
            layout.add_widget(closebutton)
            popup = Popup(title='ADD NAME',
                          title_color="white",
                          separator_color="black",
                          title_align="center",
                          separator_height="0dp",
                          background_color="red",
                          title_font="Fontyh.otf",
                          title_size="10",
                          content=layout,
                          size_hint_y=.6,
                          size_hint_x=.7)
            popup.open()
            closebutton.bind(on_release=popup.dismiss)
```

Comment: You can access the textinputs text from its attribute `TextInput.text`

Comment: @MOStudios, how can I do that? Can you please help me?

Comment: `popuptextinput.text` will contain the text input by the user

Comment: @MOStudios, when I press the closebutton I want the text to show, how can I do that?